# SQL Server 2008 : input a comma delimited list?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a query that returns 5 results, which is correct. I am now trying to re-write it into a stored procedure.

Original query:

```
    SELECT something  FROM myTable  where
   ORG + '-' + ORGSUB like '2342342-________' or
    ORG + '-' + ORGSUB like '5435354-________' or 
    ORG + '-' + ORGSUB like '_______-________'
```

but I now want to pass in `ORG` as a comma-delimited list, so it would look something like:

```
 SELECT ORG + '-' + ORGSUB   FROM myTable  where
   ORG + '-' + ORGSUB in('2342342-________','5435354-________' ,'_______-________')
```

but I am getting 0 results here.

I also tried using the Split function, like this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_Split]
(
   @psCSString VARCHAR(max)
)
RETURNS @otTemp TABLE(sID VARCHAR(50))
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @sTemp VARCHAR(50)

 WHILE LEN(@psCSString) > 0
 BEGIN
  SET @sTemp = LEFT(@psCSString, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @psCSString) - 1, -1),
                    LEN(@psCSString)))
  SET @psCSString = SUBSTRING(@psCSString,ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @psCSString), 0),
                               LEN(@psCSString)) + 1, LEN(@psCSString))
  INSERT INTO @otTemp VALUES (@sTemp)
 END

RETURN
END
```

Creating stored procedure and declaring all variables up top

```
SELECT something
FROM myTable 
where ORG + '-' + ORGSUB  in (select * from udf_Split(@orgList) as Split)
```

but this also gives me a big fat 0.

Comment: ... this can't be the most efficient way to do this.  Are you anticipating different `ORG` and `ORGSUB` values from the user?  If not (and it'll always be these three conditions), why not use something like `LEN(ORG) = 7 AND LEN(ORGSUB) = 8` (...which assumes no trimmed spaces).

Answer (score 1):

I know this does not answer the actual question, but all the solutions I have seen to handle this feel like a dirty hack to get around the previous limitations of not being able to pass multiple values to a procedure. Since the introduction of table valued parameters in sql-server 2008 I can see no reason why a delimited string would be needed within SQL:

The first step is to create your type to contain the values (I tend to use generic names so they can be reused):

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.StringList AS TABLE (Value NVARCHAR(MAX));
```

Then create your procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetFromTable @OrgList dbo.StringList READONLY
AS
    SELECT  Something
    FROM    MyTable
    WHERE   Org + '-' + OrgSub IN (SELECT Value FROM @OrgList);

GO
```

Then you can call your procedure as follows

```
DECLARE @OrgList dbo.StringList;
INSERT @OrgList VALUES 
    ('2342342', '________', 'A'),
    ('5435354', '________', 'B');

EXECUTE dbo.GetFromTable @OrgList;
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c5275/3)**

This would even afford the opputunity to create a more appropriate table:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.OrgList AS TABLE(Org VARCHAR(10), OrgSub VARCHAR(10));

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetFromTable @OrgList dbo.OrgList READONLY
AS
    SELECT  Something
    FROM    MyTable
    WHERE   EXISTS
            (   SELECT  1
                FROM    @OrgList O
                WHERE   MyTable.Org = o.Org
                AND     MyTable.OrgSub = o.OrgSub
            );

GO
```

Then to execute

```
DECLARE @OrgList dbo.OrgList;
INSERT @OrgList VALUES 
    ('2342342', '________'),
    ('5435354', '________');

EXECUTE dbo.GetFromTable @OrgList;
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2869a/1)**

If absolutely necessary to pass a comma delimited list, you could convert it to the StringList Type using XML conversion, and use the same procedure, but using a table valued parameter allows for much more flexibility than using a delimited string:

```
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(MAX) = '2342342-________,5435354-________,_______-________';

DECLARE @OrgList dbo.StringList;
INSERT @OrgList
SELECT  Y.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM    (SELECT [X] = CAST(('<X>' + REPLACE(@S, ',' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML)) X
        CROSS APPLY X.nodes('X') AS y (Y)

EXECUTE GetFromTable @OrgList
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ebdd5/5)**

Answer (score 0):

Use `charindex()` or `like`:

```
where ','+'2342342-________','5435354-________' ,'_______-________'+',' like '%,' + ORG + '-' + ORGSUB + ',%'
```

If you have spaces in the argument, then it would be more like:

```
where ','+replace(@orglist, ' ', '')+',' like '%,'+ORG+'-'+ORGSUB+',%'
```